# Fail to recording phone call on - how to solve this?

Tags: android

I know that some of the devices/country disable this option to recording the current phone call.

But there are more then one application on google store that make the phone call recording enable ( i know because i try more them one app on my device and its working fine ) - so this is possible mission on my device ( galaxy s7 ).

But still i wrote all the method that doing the recording action - and still i get an exception on recording and i don't know why and how to fix it.

(* recording from any other AudioSource - work fine )

The permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAPTURE_AUDIO_OUTPUT"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

The code:

```
public class TraceActionRecording
{

private static final String AUDIO_RECORDER_FILE_EXT_3GP = ".3gp";
private static final String AUDIO_RECORDER_FILE_EXT_MP4 = ".mp4";
private static final String AUDIO_RECORDER_FOLDER = "AudioRecorder";

private MediaRecorder recorder = null;


private String fileNameGenerator()
{
    // method that return unique file name ( and file path ) 
}

public void startRecording()
{

    recorder = new MediaRecorder();
    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_CALL);
    recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
    recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
    recorder.setOutputFile(fileNameGenerator());

    try
    {
        recorder.prepare();
        recorder.start();
    }
    catch (IllegalStateException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();      // get the exception here - exception about fail to recoding 
    }
}

public void stopRecording()
{
    if (null != recorder)
    {
        recorder.stop();
        recorder.reset();
        recorder.release();
        recorder = null;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: **1-** post the exception stacktrace, **2-** having an app in store that do what you want to do does not mean it's a straight forward task, they might be using a hidden API , reflection, and other workarounds ... in case this is not supported officially by the API.

Comment: how anyone can use a hidden API or reflection, and other workarounds ... in case this is not supported officially by the API ???

How can i have access to all those ?

Comment: you have to google it, i saw some code a while ago, but i can't remember where , using reflection , you can get a reference for a class/method/... (that is not public by default) and invoke that method